# Getting billed for Unused Elastic IP in my free Tier Account, even if I don't see any Elastic IP allocated in my Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, elastic-ip

I am getting billed for UnUsed Elastic IP Address saying it is not attached to any Running Instance
I checked the Elastic IP in EC2 and VPC dashboard, It shows no Elastic IP is allocated to me, But I am being charged , this is my free tier account

How can i check what is this IP which is still allocated to my account and get out of this continous billing in my free tier :([image]

Comment: Did you check in the exact 'region'?

Comment: You can also open a support ticket and they will help you to identify this.

Comment: Thanks, yes I call support team and they solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tag Editor](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources) in Resource Manager to see all your EIPs.

> Regions: All regions
>
> Resource types: AWS::EC2::EIP

Search for resources and then remove the ones that are not attached to any instance.